# how to show popup menu on click of checkbox column header in datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I am using the datagrid from WPF toolkit in a WPF windows application.
It has a datatemplate in the rowheader which creates a checkbox column used for selecting the rows.

If you click on the header row of the checkbox column (the top leftmost cell in the grid), it will check all the checkboxes in the grid thereby selecting all the rows.

**Relevant portions from the xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit" >

<toolkit:DataGrid Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
AutoGenerateColumns="True" SelectionMode="Extended" CanResizeRows="False">
    <toolkit:DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{
                Binding Path=IsSelected, 
                Mode=TwoWay, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                AncestorType={x:Type toolkit:DataGridRow}}}"
                />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
</toolkit:DataGrid>
</Window>
```

Now I want to know how to handle this click. I plan to handle that and show *a popup menu* instead.

Which control's click event should I wire for this?

**Answer:**
using SelectAllCommand to handle the events like so (example)

```
datagrid.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(
Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.SelectAllCommand, 
OnSelectAll, CanExecuteSelectAll));
public void OnSelectAll(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("All Selected");
    }
public void CanExecuteSelectAll(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Can I execute?");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expand the DataGrid ControlTemplate you can see that there is a Button which is bound to the SelectAllCommand.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window3"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
Title="Window3" Height="500" Width="500"
Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DataGridStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type toolkit:DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF688CAF"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode" Value="VisibleWhenSelected"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type toolkit:DataGrid}">
                    <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer" Focusable="False">
                            <ScrollViewer.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Button Command="{x:Static toolkit:DataGrid.SelectAllCommand}"
                                         Width="{Binding CellsPanelHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type toolkit:DataGrid}}}" Focusable="False">
                                            <Button.Template>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                                    <Grid>
                                                        <Rectangle x:Name="Border" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
                                                        <Polygon x:Name="Arrow" Fill="Black" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="8,8,3,3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Opacity="0.15" Points="0,10 10,10 10,0"/>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}"/>
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}"/>
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Arrow" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Button.Template>
                                            <Button.Visibility>
                                                <Binding Path="HeadersVisibility" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type toolkit:DataGrid}}">
                                                    <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                                                        <toolkit:DataGridHeadersVisibility>All</toolkit:DataGridHeadersVisibility>
                                                    </Binding.ConverterParameter>
                                                </Binding>
                                            </Button.Visibility>
                                        </Button>
                                        <toolkit:DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter" Grid.Column="1">
                                            <toolkit:DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter.Visibility>
                                                <Binding Path="HeadersVisibility" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type toolkit:DataGrid}}">
                                                    <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                                                        <toolkit:DataGridHeadersVisibility>Column</toolkit:DataGridHeadersVisibility>
                                                    </Binding.ConverterParameter>
                                                </Binding>
                                            </toolkit:DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter.Visibility>
                                        </toolkit:DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter>
                                        <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" CanHorizontallyScroll="False" CanVerticallyScroll="False"/>
                                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Orientation="Vertical" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"/>
                                        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type toolkit:DataGrid}}}"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Orientation="Horizontal" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </ScrollViewer.Template>
                            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <toolkit:DataGrid Name="dataGrid" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                      CanUserResizeRows="False" 
                      SelectionMode="Extended" 
                      AutoGenerateColumns="True" Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle1}">
        <toolkit:DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{
                        Binding Path=IsSelected, 
                        Mode=TwoWay, 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                        AncestorType={x:Type toolkit:DataGridRow}}}"
                        />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
    </toolkit:DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

You can override that Button's Command to perform your own logic or even replace the button with a different control.